# string null checking from different style

Tags: c#

I don't know before this asked or not, but I am confuse in below of code block.

**CODE 1**

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text.Trim()))
{
      // Code to execute
}
```

**CODE 2**

```
if (control.Text.Trim() == "")
{
      // Code to execute
}
```

**CODE 3**

```
if (control.Text.Trim() == null)
{
      // Code to execute
}
```

**CODE 4**

```
if (control.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
{
      // Code to execute
}
```

According to me all are working to me.

I just feeling wonder that what is the different in between in this 4 code block.

Comment: If `Text == null` all of them throw when you attempt to call `Trim`. So second one is the only meaningful check. First two are equivalent, third one is always false.

Comment: the code 2 is not null checking it is string.empty

Comment: @Mark None of them is checking for `null`.

Comment: I think your confusion lies in the difference between `null` and an empty string. In .NET, `null` is the absence of an object, which is different from an empty string (`""` or `string.Empty`), which is different from a string which contains only whitespace (`"  "`). All of these code samples do different things (except 2 and 4 are identical). There's also a `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method which checks for any of those scenarios. A textbox's text will never be null, but strings coming from other places may be, so it's always important that you consider null when you're looking at strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from primitives:

The first block checks if the string `control.Text.Trim()` is `null` or `String.Empty`.

The second block checks if the string `control.Text.Trim()` is `""`.

The third block checks if the string `control.Text.Trim()` is `null`.

The fourth block checks if the string `control.Text.Trim()` is `String.Empty`; this is exactly the same as the second block: `""` equals `String.Empty`.

Fine, that's easy to understand. However, note that `String.Trim()` will never return `null`. Thus, the first block is equivalent to `control.Text.Trim() == String.Empty`. This is same as the second block and the fourth block, again because `""` equals `String.Empty`. The third block will never be hit, ever.

Thus, the first, second and fourth blocks are equivalent to checking if `control.Trim` the empty string and the third block is useless and impossible to satisfy. Be careful, if `control` is `null` or `control.Text` is `null` you will hit an exception. Thus, you should strongly consider using [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) and replacing everything with:

```
if(control != null && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text)) {
    // code to execute
}
```

(unless you have some sort of guarantee that `control` is not `null`, in which case leave off the first part of the `if`).

Comment: Hay sorry, for late update, but please check there is other code block...

Comment: `String.Empty` is the same thing as `""` it is just another way of representing it.

Comment: It's the same as the second block because `""` equals `String.Empty`.

Comment: Heat's off to you sir...

Comment: Interesting fact I just learned testing. `Control.Text` can never be null (unless it is overrided), if you assign it null it sets it to `""`.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: Yes, I think we were commenting to each other [at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131200/string-null-checking-from-different-style/18131273?noredirect=1#comment26551465_18131319).

Answer (score 0):

control.Text.Trim() is never going to be null

control might be

control.Text might be

in which case all three versions will blow chunks...

```
private static bool validControl(Control argControl)
{
   return (argControl != null) && (argControl.Text != null) && (argControl.Text.Trim() != ""));
}

if (validControl(control))
{
   // code to execute
}
```

maybe

Comment: It looks like you're missing the ends of your

Comment: `argControl.Text != null` is not necessary, `Control.Text` can never be null, if you set the value to null it just changes it to `""`

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: Not true. It's virtual, an overriding class can permit the setter to accept `null`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, not an assumption I'd care to rely on. What would be the point of not checking it?

Answer (score 0):

More proper would be:

```
 if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text))
 {
   // Code to execute
 }
```

that way you avoid null reference exception.

All your examples have the same bug, they will throw exception if variable is null.

You should also see diference between string.empty ("") and null, those are not the same things. Code 4 and code 2 are the same but both would throw if Text is null.

Comment: this will throw one if control is null